# Can"t build Keystore for 'Build and release an Android app'

Tags: java, android, flutter, firebase, keystore

[image]

I want to create a keystore for an application I have created.
But it didn't work.

Want to be successful in creating a Keystore

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.